# Filling 2D array diagonally

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I've been trying to get a 10x10 2D array filled diagonally as in the image below for a couple hours now, but after checking every possible way to use rows and columns I still can't seem to identify my misunderstanding of the code.

What I'm supposed to get:

[image]

This is how far I've gotten, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
 int n = 1;
 for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
    for (int j=9-i ; j>=7-i; j--) {
       if (j>=0)
          m[i][j] = n++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It looks like the issue in your code is related to the inner loop's termination condition and indexing. Check that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to loop your rows, and knowing that it's a diagonal loop, the starting point at each step will be the (i, i) tuple. Starting from there, an inner loop loops up to 2 further elements and updates the values at the given place if they are inside bounds. Whenever we set a value to a given element, we decrement `currentIndex`, so we will not have to worry about its value.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

// The main method must be in a class named "Main".
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int currentIndex = 27;
        int[][] array = new int[10][10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= i + 2 && (j < array[i].length); j++) {
                array[i][j] = currentIndex--;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                System.out.print((array[j][i] > 9 ? "" : " ") + array[j][i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.mycompiler.io/view/0rg7WTh30b9

Comment: That's definitely an improvement from my own array, but it's still not quite right. I basically need the array you've provided me with but transposed (as seen in the image I inserted beforehand)

Comment: @blackburrow112 thanks for the answer. You are correct, fixing it.

Comment: @blackburrow112 edited my answer, adjusted the code. Can you check it now?

Answer (score 0):

Another one to study:

```
class Main { 
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int[][] m = new int[10][10];
    int curValue = 27;
    for(int r=0, c=0; r<m.length && c<m[0].length; r++, c++) {
        for(int i=0; i<3 && r+i<m.length; i++) {      
          m[r+i][c] = curValue;
          curValue--;
        }
    }   
    displayArray(m);
  } 

  public static void displayArray(int[][] arr) {
    for(int[] row : arr) {
      for(int num : row) {
        if (num < 10) {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(num + " ");
      }  
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  
}
```

Output:

```
27  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
26 24  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
25 23 21  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0 22 20 18  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0 19 17 15  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0 16 14 12  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0 13 11  9  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0 10  8  6  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  7  5  3  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  2  1
```

Comment: This answer seems to be the same as my older answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad Hmmm...it's different enough that I felt it was worthy of posting. You also did not fill the array correctly in my opinion, which is why you had to do a ~weird transposition thing~ in your displaying of it. Arrays are typically row major and column minor.

Comment: I don't see the difference to be honest. Can you describe what the fundamental difference is between the two answers? As about the transposition issue, it was indeed an issue in my initial answer, but then I edited it at 16:51 and then at 17:12 you have written your answer and at 18:38 you claimed that my answer does not fill the array correctly, referring to an issue that was fixed on 16:51.

Comment: Sure. In both your nested loops, the outer and inner loops use `i` and `j` respectively. But you filled it with `array[i][j]` and displayed it with `array[j][i]`. Note the switching of `i` and `j` between the two. In the filling part, you made your numbers go decreasing to the right in the same ROW, before moving down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, using a single *loop*.

Where *m = n*, traverse *m*, assigning *v* to *n*, *v − 1* to *n* at *m + 1*, and *v − 2* to *n* at *m + 2*.

```java
int[][] a = new int[10][10];
for (int m = 0, v = 27; m < 10; m++) {
    a[m][m] = v--;
    if (m + 1 < 10) {
        a[m + 1][m] = v--;
        if (m + 2 < 10)
            a[m + 2][m] = v--;
    }
}
```

Output

```
  27   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
  26  24   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
  25  23  21   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
   .  22  20  18   .   .   .   .   .   .
   .   .  19  17  15   .   .   .   .   .
   .   .   .  16  14  12   .   .   .   .
   .   .   .   .  13  11   9   .   .   .
   .   .   .   .   .  10   8   6   .   .
   .   .   .   .   .   .   7   5   3   .
   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   4   2   1
```